# pandas: How to merge multiple dataframes with same column names on one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have N dataframes:

```
df1:
time  data
1.0   a1
2.0   b1
3.0   c1


df2:
time  data
1.0   a2
2.0   b2
3.0   c2



df3:
time  data
1.0   a3
2.0   b3
3.0   c3
```

I want to merge all of them on id, thus getting

```
time  data1    data2    data3
1.0   a1       a2       a3
2.0   b1       b2       b3
3.0   c1       c2       c3
```

I can assure all the ids are the same in all dataframes.

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for list of `DataFrame`s - only necessary create index by `id` for each `DaatFrame`. Also for avoid duplicated columns names is added `keys` parameter, but it create `MultiIndex` in output. So added `map` with `format` for flatten it:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [x.set_index('id') for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=range(1, len(dfs) + 1))
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[1]}{0[0]}'.format)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id data1 data2 data3
0   1    a1    a2    a3
1   2    b1    b2    b3
2   3    c1    c2    c3
```

Comment: can you explain please? What is the `'{0[1]}{0[0]}'` part? Would also like to understand the rest

Comment: on `pd.concat(...)`: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9, 92994), indices imply (9, 89954)`. All of my 9 dfs are of length 10000. What did i do wrong?

Comment: @Gulzar - there are duplicates in `id` values

Comment: Well in that case, my question doesn't fit my data. Should I ask a new one or edit this one? My 'id' is actually 'timestamp' which are float values. I guess some tolerance is needed.

Comment: @Gulzar - I can edit, only whats happen in output if `df3` is like `{'id': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 3}, 'data': {0: 'a3', 1: 'b3', 2: 'c3'}}` ?

Comment: I edited. If the same values occur for a time entry, take the 1st one, or the last one, or a random one, which ever would be the most convenient for you. "same" should be by some tolerance

Comment: @Gulzar - It is then more complicated, maybe you can create new question